# How to sum values in columns in group, keeping row number same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, group-by

My dataset looks like this:

```
val1   val2   val3  val4
a1       b      1     c
a1       d      1     k
a2       b      3     c
a2       d      4     k
```

I want to sum values in column "val3" grouped by "val1" while keeping all other values same. the number of rows in dataframe shouldn't change. so desired result is:

```
val1   val2   val3  val4
a1       b      2     c
a1       d      2     k
a2       b      7     c
a2       d      7     k
```

how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` here:

```
df['val3'] = df.groupby('val1')['val3'].transform(sum)
```

**Output**:

```
  val1 val2  val3 val4
0   a1    b     2    c
1   a1    d     2    k
2   a2    b     7    c
3   a2    d     7    k
```